How to simplify $O(\log (n!))$?
I have a problem with this time complexity: $\log (n!)+\frac{5}{2}n\log\log n$. I'm not sure how to deal with the $n!$ term. I know from calculus class that the sequence $n!$ is bigger than any exponential $a^n$, so for sure $O(\log (n!))$ is at least $O(\log(a^n))=O(n\log a)= O(n)$. I also know that it is smaller than $n^n$, so $O(\log(n!))$ is at most $O(\log(n^n)))=O(n\log n)$. But is it one of the two bounds I found? Or is it something in the middle? I would like to simplify the asymptotic time complexity I wrote at the beginning, and I wonder if we know precisely what $O(\log(n!))$ is.

Without Stirling the lower bound estimation can be found here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/48358/4287

You can solve it using Stirling's Formula.
From Stirling's formula we know that $$n!=O\left(\sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \right) \ ,$$
so, passing to logarithm, we have:
$$\log(n!) = O\left(\log \left( \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \right) \right) = O(\log n) + O(n (\log n-\log e) = O(n\log n) \ .$$
So, at the end, your time complexity reduces to $O(n\log n)$.

One warning, one comment: Big-O does not stay intact after taking the logarithm if your values are close to 1. And many times f(n) is not O(g(n)) but  log f(n)) = O(log(g(n))). For example if f(n) is between k-th root and k-th power of g(n). In this case here everything is fine.

It is rather straightforward to show $\log(n!) = O(n\log n)$ without using Stirling's approximation or any integration:
\begin{align}
\log(n!) &= \log (n\times (n-1) \times\cdots\times 2 \times 1) \\
&= \log(n) + \log(n-1) + \cdots+ \log(2) + \log(1) \\
&\le \log(n) + \log(n) + \cdots+ \log(n) + \log(n) \\
&= n\log n .
\end{align}

That's right. Or simply $n!<n^n$. But then you don't know if it is tight.

You can lower bound the first $n/2$ terms by $\log n/2$ to get tightness

Without knowing Stirling,
$$\log(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k).$$
We can replace the sum by an integral because for $t\in[k,k+1]$, $\log(k)\le\log(t)$ and
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k)<\int_{t=1}^{n+1}\log(t)\,dt=(t\log(t)-t)\bigg|_1^{n+1}=(n+1)\log(n+1)+1$$
which is $O(n\log(n))$.
